# How use nginx to create subdomains and map API to localhost:80?

Tags: docker, nginx, subdomain

I have a docker that run my **api** on `localhost:80` and 2 folder for my **fronts**.

Here is what I want:

- If I visit `api.example.com` map it to `localhost:80`
- If I visit `admin.example.com` map it to folder `~/admin`
- If i visit `example.com` map it to folder `~/front`

How can do this?

Comment: What did you try? This is pretty basic nginx rewriting/proxying so many other questions and tutorials can give you the solution for that.

Comment: Can you give me a link?
Every link that i see is just to use subdomain to point some directory not a docker service running on localhost.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/  and https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fullexample2/ they both show you how to map a given URL to a local path (see `location` and `root`) as well as doing proxying for some other URL (see `location` and `proxy_pass`). And server blocks for each different website name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer and thanks from @Patrick-Mevzek.

I solved my problem by adding below server blocks to my nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    root         /home/erfantahvieh.com/front;

    server_name domain.example www.domain.example;                

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
         autoindex on;
         autoindex_exact_size off;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    root         /home/erfantahvieh.com/admin;

    server_name admin.domain.example www.admin.domain.example;                

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    server_name api.domain.example www.api.domain.example;                

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/;
    }
}
```